# Juego en 2D, no realiza transición de Run a Jump en Unity

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Actualmente estoy creando un juego 2D, al cual le he añadido dos parámetros booleanos en Unity y que luego he referenciado en C#.
Lo tengo configurado para que el personaje esté vivo y en el suelo, corriendo (Run). He añadido transiciones desde Run a Jump, desde Jump a Run, desde Jump y Run hacia Die respectivamente.

El problema es que al reproducir el juego, cuando tecleo Space o botón izquierdo del mouse, el personaje realiza el salto en pantalla pero no ejecuta la animación de Jump; es decir, no transitan las animaciones de Run -> Jump. Adjunto código revisado, al cual no le encuentro fallo. Seguro que será una tontería pero no la consigo ver.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*Variables del movimiento del personaje
    //Con la clase Rigidbody2D estamos declarando el tipo de cuerpo rígido en 2D que en este caso en Unity hemos especificado que es Dynamyc. A este RigidBody2D le he 
    hemos llamado PlayerRigidBody
    Y hemos declarado también una capa de máscara para el suelo, la cual hemos llamado groundMask, aplicada a todo aquello que sufrirá*/
    //Para modificar una animación en nuestro videojuego por código, haremos lo siguiente: Declarar una clase privada Animator con el nombre "animator"
    /*Referenciamos las dos variables bool de Unity aquí de esta manera: private const string "       " = "     "; Donde "const" es una variable constante que no va a cambiar
    a lo largo del código.*/
    

    public float jumpForce = 15f;
    private Rigidbody2D PlayerRigidbody;
    private Animator animator;

    private const string STATE_ALIVE = "isAlive";
    private const string STATE_ON_THE_GROUND = "isOnTheGround";

    public LayerMask groundMask;


    //Aquí es cuando todos los elementos, todos todos, despiertan en el juego. A diferencia de Start que es empezar el juego pero con todos los elementos despiertos ya.
    //Un simil sería con un coche. Cuando introducimos la llave de arranque sería Awake, cuando giramos la llave para arrancar sería Start.
    //Invocamos el GameObject "PlayerRigidBody" y cargamos la variable instanciada RidgiBody2D a través del método GetComponent para que añada el componente al PlayerRigidBody.
    //De la misma manera hacemos con Animator, que se instancia y se añade al Awake a través del método GetComponent.
    void Awake()
    {
        PlayerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        /*Configuramos el Animator aquí en Start de manera que: Indicamos que nuestro Animator configure mediante el método SetBool (Son variables Boolianas) la variable STATE_ALIVE
         * en true; ya que al empezar el juego, el personaje está vivo y la condición booliana es verdadera. Para STATE_ON_THE_GROUND se haría de manera similar,
         excepto que la condición no es indiferente colocarla en true o false, porque el personaje al comienzo puede estar sobre el suelo o en el aire, caer por la gravedad
        al propio suelo y que el código haga su trabajo por sí solo.*/
        animator.SetBool(STATE_ALIVE, true);
        animator.SetBool(STATE_ON_THE_GROUND, true);
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame (es decir, 60 veces por segundo, ya que nuestro juego correrá a 60 fps)
    //Declaramos una sentencia if que dice: Si la entrada de datos(input) detecta(GetKey) que se ha pulsado(KeyCode) la tecla cuya clave es Space, O(||) Si la entrada de datos detecta
    //que pulsamos la tecla izquierda del ratón (0), delegamos la tarea al método Jump();  
    /*ATENCION BUG, ENLAZADO CON (this.transform.position): En el input.GetKey, GetKey (mantener pulsado, es la metralleta de Call Of Dutty)
     * no nos sirve porque a la misma vez que pulsamos la barra espaciadora, estamos ejecutando por 6 (la fuerza del Jump) la propia ejecución, por lo tanto 
     * el personaje no baja hasta dentro de 60 segundos (60 fps, 60 frames por segundo). Por lo tanto sustituimos GetKey por GetKeyDown que detecta la bajada del botón 
     * para que se aplique correctamente el salto, y no tener que calcular milimétricamente la distancia de choque del personaje con el suelo (0.2f, 2.0f, 1.5f, etc)*/
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Jump(); 
        }



        /*Aquí utilizamos el método (isTouchingTheGround) que calcula la distancia del personaje hasta el suelo, cuando salta, para en este caso utilizar el resultado para configurar
        una variable del Animator.*/

        animator.SetBool(STATE_ON_THE_GROUND, IsTouchingTheGround());
        

        /*Vamos a dibujar un Gizmo propio, en concreto una recta que atraviese nuestro personaje para que detecte la distancia del 1.35f hasta dónde llega.
        Para dibujar un Gizmo se suele utilizar el método Update, así lo tenemos localizado antes lanzar el juego a Producción.
        Invocamos la clase Debug (Algo así como el Modo Prueba, para poder visualizar y probar cosas), llamamos al método DrawRay (Dibujar rayo, para que
        nos dibuje una pequeña raya o rayo atravesando el personaje, desde el centro del personaje (this.transform.position)
        hacia abajo (vector2.Down) y se multiplica por la distancia al suelo desde el personaje; y el rayo será de color rojo.*/

        Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, Vector2.down * 1.35f, Color.red);


        /*Si queremos variar la masa de nuestro personaje deberemos también variar el Jump Force del mismo, ya que contra mayor sea la masa de nuestro personaje,
        menor será aceleración de su salto. F =m.a ; m = f/a;
        Si checkeamos la "Auto mass" del Inspector del Player en Unity, el motor gráfico asignará una masa relativa a su RididBody, pero no variará automáticamente
        el Jump Force, por lo tanto al ser la auto mass de 2.39, registraremos un Jump Force de 20 y así el personaje saltará correctamente.*/
    }



    


    /* Dentro del método Jump(), ¿quién es el encargado de responder a acciones físicas?, PlayerRigidBody. Por lo tanto invocamos a PlayerRigidBody, y le aplicamos una fuerza; 
     * invocando el método AddForce, la cual tendrá que ir hacia arriba, por lo tanto se lo indicamos con Vector2.up, que se multiplica por la fuerza del salto (6F); y un segundo parametro
     * que es el modo en el que se aplica la fuerza (ForceMode2D.Impulse), que sería aplicándola de una sola vez con un impulso, no con una fuerza constante.*/
    //Cuando invocamos el método Jump no debería aplicar la fuerza vertical a menos que el personaje esté tocando el suelo. 
    //Hemos añadido un IF con el método IsTouchingTheGround() (Estoy tocando el suelo) para que: Si el personaje está tocando el suelo, aplica la fuerza vertical declarada en Jump. 
    void Jump()
    { 
        if (IsTouchingTheGround())
        {
            PlayerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    //Nos indica si el personaje está tocando o no el suelo.
    /* Vamos a declarar un método para calcular la distancia de choque contra el suelo (groundMask) que nos devolverá un valor booliano respondiendo
     * a la pregunta ¿está tocando el suelo?. 
     * Dentro de IsTouchingTheGround ponemos un if, e invocamos al motor de Physisc2D.Raycast (Raycast es el método para indicar que vamos a trazar un rayo invisible
     en Unity), desde la posición actual (this.transformn.position) hacia abajo (vector2.down) hacia una distancia máxima de 20 cms (o.2f) para que choque contra la capa groundMask
    la capa del suelo que hemos declarado)*/
    /*ATENCION BUG : Hemos observado que con la distancia de 0.2f el personaje no salta, por lo tanto hemos calculado 1.35f metros ya que la posición declarada en
    (this.transform.position) es desde el centro del personaje, a la altura del bolsillo, y no es suficiente 20 centimetros.*/
    //Si se cumple toda la sentencia IF, es que estamos tocando el suelo.
    //TODO (TODO significa ToDo en ingles, para hacer más tarde)
    //A la pregunta IsTouchingTheGround, si la respuesta es "SÍ" nos devolverá un valor true. Si la respuesta es "No", nos devolverá un valor false. 
    bool IsTouchingTheGround()
    {
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector2.down, 1.35f, groundMask))
        {
            //TODO: programar lógica de contacto con el suelo
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: programar lógica de no contacto con el suelo
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código como texto con formato de código. Las preguntas que tienen código en imagen no son bien recibidas ya que provocan que la persona que desea ayudar tenga que reescribir todo el código.  Saludos